# PDO does not receive table fom called sp

Tags: php, mysql

I am new with PDO an PHP.
I wrote an SP to get log entries from a mariaDB.
If I call the procedure directly in phpMyAdmin all works fine.
But using PDO in PHP I don't get any rows.

```
  $sql = "SET @p0='".$name1."'; "
    . "SET @p1='".$name2."'; "
    . "SET @p2='".$pid."'; "
    . "SET @p3='".$log_class."'; "
    . "CALL `show_log_filter`(@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3);";

try
{
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row)
    {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['log_id']."</td></tr>";
        //more echos...
    }

} catch (PDOException  $ex) {
    echo "<p>".$ex->getMessage()."</p>";
}
```

I do this the same way multiple times in my project but in this case it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: update your question and add  your $sql code content

Comment: You can only call one query at a time with PDO. Run the first 4 in separate queries, then use the last for your foreach.

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionally, if your database driver supports it, you may also bind parameters for output as well as input

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_returns_something(?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $return_value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000); 
$stmt->execute(); // call the stored procedure
print "procedure returned $return_value\n";
```